# how to repeat the loop statement by having a conditional value in java?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

What i want to do is, taking input value in variable only0, and the value must be only 0, if the user inputs value 0, then it must show ("we welcome you") line and if not then repeat the same question

```
System.out.println(" ****Press 0 to start****");
int only0 = sc.nextInt();    //taking input of the user
        
        
if (only0 == 0) {
        
    System.out.println(" We Welcome You :-)");
     
} else {

    System.out.println(" YOU ARE REQUESTED TO PRESS ONLY 0 :-)");
            
}// if end
```

Comment: You should include the loop in your code. Otherwise we're just guessing. I would suggest using a break statement just after the "We Welcome You" print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of invalid input, you need to loop back to prompt the user to enter the value again. One of the best ways to do it is by using  a `do-while` loop as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int only0;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            // Start with assuming that the input will be valid. In case of invalid input,
            // assign false to valid which will force the loop to run again
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter zero: ");
            try {
                // Use Scanner#nextLine to consume Enter as well
                only0 = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                if (only0 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(" We Welcome You :-)");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" YOU ARE REQUESTED TO PRESS ONLY 0 :-)");
                    valid = false;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("This is not a number.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter zero: 1
 YOU ARE REQUESTED TO PRESS ONLY 0 :-)
Enter zero: a
This is not a number.
Enter zero: 0
 We Welcome You :-)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to assume the user is not always going to enter an integer so I load it as a string and then parse to an int to handle off cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            
            int only0 = 0;
            
            try {
                only0 = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Only enter an integer! Try again.");
                continue;
            }
            
            if (only0 == 0) {
                System.out.println("We welcome you.");
                break;
                
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter 0!");
                continue;
            }
            
        }
        
        scan.close();
        
    }
```

Comment: helped me alot!! -- Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java doesn't do that(I suppose you are talking about Goto Statement). However, you can still simulate with recursion without looping statement:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test run = new Test();
        run.ask();
    }
    private void ask(){
        System.out.print("Press 0 to start");
        if(input.nextInt()==0){
            System.out.println(" We Welcome You :-)");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(" YOU ARE REQUESTED TO PRESS ONLY 0 :-)");
            ask();
        }
    }
}
```